# Can't access CentOS in VirtualBox

Tags: ssh, connection, virtualbox, centos7, xshell

I've installed a CentOS7 in the VirtualBox, the CentOS and Host can ping sucessfully each other.

Myhost ip is 192.168.1.7, CentOS is 192.168.1.111
[image]

[image]

I also open the 22 port in the CentOS

[image]

But I can't access the CenOS via the Xshell client.

[image]

Here is the conf of CentOS net

[image]

Could someone help me on this, thanks a lot!

Comment: it looks like your sshd is down. try ```telnet localhost 22``` at CentOS first. StackOverflow is dedicated to software development and you question is off-topic here. You will have better chances for the answer either at  [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) or [ServelFault](https://serverfault.com/) or [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/)

Comment: Thank you ,will post the question to the webs you advised